# Android Gmail attachment

Tags: android, gmail, attachment

I'm trying to get the name of the file attached to an email on the gmail app? Can anyone point in the direction of getting the file name ? I can get the attachemnt, just don't know how to get the original file name.

Answer (score 0):

Access to attachments (except through the app giving them to you with an ACTION_VIEW) intent is not supported, and trying to directly access the provider is likely going to cause problems for your app as Gmail changes.